# Разграничение прав доступа

Tags: php, mysql

Приветствую!

Пишу тут CMS - проблема появилась: не могу придумать как правильно сделать разграничение прав доступа к объектам модулей.

Кто что может подсказать?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самой корректной следует считать группо-ролийную систему, по моему мнению.

Т.Е. группа даёт определённые права, роль - расширяет или сужает эти права (читай-конкретизирует).

Это даёт очень гибкую систему управления правами, но при этом сложную в реализации. Сложна она тем, что если предоставлять каждой группе своё пространство "свобод", то при выполнении операций следует валидировать действие с точки зрения сложения прав группы и прав роли. В сторону уменьшения сделать это не сложно - отсутсвует разрешение - до свидания. Но с точки зрения расширения - тяжело. Необходимо ли включать пространство свобод другой группы при наличии в роли соответсвующих правил - это загадка. А вы подбираете решение. Проектируйте так, чтобы не получалось таких коллизий и права роли находились в пределах прав группы и не больше. А если необходимо расширение прав - новая группа.

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю вам надо посмотреть как это реализовано в популярных фреймворках.
В Kohana система ролей пользователей.
Или если вам нужна более гибкая система ACL Zend.
Эту систему легко выдернуть из Zend Framework есть реализации этой системы и для других фреймворков.